# Getting Google Vulnerability Mail

Tags: android, kotlin, android-security

I am getting mail from Google about SSL Error Handler, TrustManager, HostnameVerifier vulnerability. I added all certificates for https requests in my project. I use Retrofit and pin my certificates with OkHttpClient.

Getting mail that saying found that your app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users. Apps with these vulnerabilities can expose user information or damage a user’s device, and may be considered to be in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy.

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please migrate your apps to use the updated software as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

[image]

Links are:

1. [https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188426)
2. https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387
3. https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188426

And here is my code:

OkHttpCertificatePinner.java

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
public interface OkHttpCertificatePinner {
    OkHttpClient.Builder pinCertificate(okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpBuilder);
}
```

RawCertificatePinner.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RawRes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

public final class RawCertificatePinner implements OkHttpCertificatePinner {

    private static final String CERTIFICATE_TYPE = "BKS";
    private static final String DEFAULT_TLS_VERSION = "TLSv1.2";

    private final Context context;
    @RawRes
    private final int certificate;
    private final String certificatePassword;

    public RawCertificatePinner(@NonNull Context context,
                                @RawRes int certificate,
                                @NonNull String certificatePassword) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.certificate = certificate;
        this.certificatePassword = certificatePassword;
    }

    @Override
    public OkHttpClient.Builder pinCertificate(OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpBuilder) {
        final KeyStore trustedCertificate = getTrustedCertificate();
        final TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = getTrustManagerFactory(trustedCertificate);
        final SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContext(trustManagerFactory);
        X509TrustManager trustManager = getX509TrustManager(trustManagerFactory);
        okhttpBuilder.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), trustManager);
        return okhttpBuilder;
    }

    private KeyStore getTrustedCertificate() {
        KeyStore trusted = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            trusted = KeyStore.getInstance(CERTIFICATE_TYPE);
             in = context.getResources().openRawResource(certificate);
            trusted.load(in, certificatePassword.toCharArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(in != null){
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return trusted;
    }

    private TrustManagerFactory getTrustManagerFactory(KeyStore trustedCertificate) {
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = null;
        try {
            trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustedCertificate);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return trustManagerFactory;
    }

    private SSLContext getSSLContext(TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory) {
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(DEFAULT_TLS_VERSION);
            sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sslContext;
    }

    private X509TrustManager getX509TrustManager(TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory) {
        final TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

        if (trustManagers == null
                || trustManagers.length != 1
                || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {

            final IllegalStateException e = new IllegalStateException("Wrong trust manager: " + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
            Log.d("ThrowableReporter",e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }

        return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try and do what the message says? `Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please migrate your apps to use the updated software as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK`. Your actual code doesn't have much to do with the error description there.